# jquery.hover on iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, css

I use jquery.hover to toggle a class when someone mouses over a link.  On the iphone when someone taps the link, it toggles the class on, but it doesn't ever toggle the class off until they tap somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the event section of the [Mobile Safari Guide](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

> If the user taps a nonclickable element, no events are generated. If the user taps a clickable element, events arrive in this order: mouseover, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup, and click. **The mouseout event occurs only if the user taps on another clickable item**

There are a variety of touch events you can use on mobile Safari rather than mouse events.  For example you can use the `touchStart` and `touchEnd` events to determine when the user has put their finger down/taken it off on an element

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion with iPhone web apps is to not use the mouseover events... If there isn't a mouse (which there isn't), it doesn't make for the best user experience. Can you key it off of a different action?

Answer (score 0):

I use use a 'close button' for large rollover nav divs when viewed in iphone. Easily overlooked solution for a lot of rollout situations.